# How to check punctuation(like comma,period,colon etc..) followed by space or not. In a title column using SQL, REG

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to check punctuation(like comma,period,colon etc..) followed by space or not, in a title column  using  SQL, REG

Good example:

```
Symphony No. 4 in A Major, Op. 53: IV. Allegro molto
```

Bad example:

```
Symphony No.4 in A Major, Op.53: IV. Allegro molto
```

I need query like

```
SELECT COUNT (1)
  FROM actual_configs
 WHERE......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t (col) as 
(
              select 'Symphony No. 4 in A Major, Op. 53: IV. Allegro molto' from dual
   union all  select 'Symphony No.4 in A Major, Op.53: IV. Allegro molto'   from dual
)
select  *
from    t  
where   regexp_like (col,'([[:punct:]])([^ ])') 
;
```

---

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                        COL                         |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| Symphony No.4 in A Major, Op.53: IV. Allegro molto |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

---

For debugging purposes

```
with t (col) as 
(
              select 'Symphony No. 4 in A Major, Op. 53: IV. Allegro molto' from dual
   union all  select 'Symphony No.4 in A Major, Op.53: IV. Allegro molto'   from dual
)
select  case when regexp_like (col,'([[:punct:]])([^ ])') then 0 else 1 end  as is_valid
       ,col
       ,regexp_replace (col,'([[:punct:]])([^ ])','<<<\1>>>\2')              as show_issues

from    t  
;
```

---

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| IS_VALID |                         COL                          |                          SHOW_ISSUES                           |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | Symphony No. 4 in A Major, Op. 53: IV. Allegro molto | Symphony No. 4 in A Major, Op. 53: IV. Allegro molto           |
|        0 | Symphony No.4 in A Major, Op.53: IV. Allegro molto   | Symphony No<<<.>>>4 in A Major, Op<<<.>>>53: IV. Allegro molto |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: "For debugging purposes" is a nice touch, I'll try to remember to add similar hints when they make sense and they are not too complicated.